# Disable scroll top event on iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an iframe in my main page. The iframe generates images and sends it to the parent page. My problem is that after iframe generates images my parent page scroll back to the top. How can i disable scroll top event in iframe?

Fix :
Setting the iframe to display none fix this issue but iframe in display none does not work for firefox. The iframe does not get loaded if it's set to display none so instead of I've used visibility : hidden. But using visibility hidden I encounter the problem above.

Sample code

```
<iframe id="image_source" src="http://local.testImages.com" width="100%" height="0px" style="visibility :hidden"></iframe>
```

This iframe is located on top of the page. Everytime it gets updated my main page scrolls back to top which the iframe is located.

How can i disable the main page from scrolling to top? or disable scroll event?

Thanks,

Comment: visibility hidden so it can't be seen, position absolute so it doesn't impact layout, low z-index and small width/height so it can't be clicked.

Comment: @KevinB, I've added what you said and it still scrolls back to where the iframe is located.

Comment: What exactly is causing the scroll? things being added to the page? things being removed from the page? the hash changing? what?

Comment: Inside the iframe there is a scroll event when processing of images is complete. I think this is the one causing it. How can I disable it in my main page.

Comment: that doesn't sound plausible. scroll events don't scroll the page, scroll event handlers do. If the iframe's scroll event handler is specifically affecting the scroll of the **parent** page, the only way to stop that would be to change that handler.

Comment: What do you suggest that I would do? using display : none fixes this issue but again it does not work in firefox.

Comment: you first need to find the cause. Without a cause, solving this is a guessing game. default scroll events in iframes don't cause the parent to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

This code will mostly fix it but it does cause some glitches with scrolling to fast

```
oldscrole=window.scrollY;setInterval("if(window.scrollY==0&&window.scrollY+500<oldscrole){window.scroll(window.scrollY,oldscrole)}oldscrole=window.scrollY",1)
```

Comment: just paste it in as javascript and it will revert scrolls that scroll to the top of the page to fast